# Testcafe - Filtering on Tests works from Command Line but not from runner

Tags: testing, filter, metadata, testcafe, fixtures

I'm actually trying to use a test-runner file to figure out all my configs from this file. I'm using tests for Smoke and Regression scripts. So, i want my tests to run based on Smoke or Functional test metadata that i choose from the tet runner file. The filter works when i give in package.json file. But it is not working in test runner file using runner.filter

Kindly, help if someone knows the reason.

Below is the snippet from Test.js file,

```
test.meta('smokeTest','true)('Testing application as admin', async t=> {
await t.click(elements.submitButton);
})
```

Whereas the test-runner file is,

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

try {
    const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

    const failedCount = await runner
        .src('./tests/fixture1.js')
        .filter(testMeta => {return testMeta.smokeTest === 'true';})
        .browsers('chrome')
        .run();

    console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
}
finally {
    await testcafe.close();
}
```

The filter works when we run it from command line like,

testcafe chrome ./tests/fixture1.js --test-meta smokeTest=true

When I used the test-runner file, it says **the filter settings has excluded all the tests, try to modify the settings**

Comment: We will be happy to help you and diagnose this problem, However, I didn't manage to reproduce it.
Submit a bug report here: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md)
And add your environment information there, as well as a sample project and tests, so that we can suggest a solution for you

Comment: I just updated the snippets in the description and the error i faced. Let me know the possible solution please.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402657/reference/testcafe-api/runner/filter), you need to specify your filter callback arguments in the following way: `function(testName, fixtureName, fixturePath, testMeta, fixtureMeta)`. Your `.filter` should be rewritten as follows:

```js
.filter((testName, fixtureName, fixturePath, testMeta, fixtureMeta) => testMeta.smokeTest === 'true')
```

Comment: Great! That really worked. Thanks for your help!!